# how compare 2 datafram and choose some rows of one of them which has same value in some of columns of another df

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 data frame df1 and df2, I want to check if in df2 there is any row whose have the same value as in df1 for 4 columns?

```
               df1 

                    a1    a2.    a3     a4
                    1      2      3     4
                    1      2      3     5
                    1      6      3     3
                    1      2      8     4


               df2 

                    a1    a2.    a3     a4
                    1      2      3     9
                    4      2      8     5
                    1      6      3     7
                    5      2      8     2
```

suppose I want to select rows in df2 whose have the same value in df1 in a1 , a2  and a3:

output

```
                    a1    a2.    a3     a4
                    1      2      3     9
                    1      6      3     7
```

Comment: Why do you only select the first row of `df1`? The second row has the same three entries for `a1`, `a2`, `a3`.

Comment: I edited the out put

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using base R, we could `paste` the columns of interest row-wise for both the dataframe and select the rows in `df2` which match.

```
cols <- paste0("a", 1:3)

df2[do.call(paste, c(df2[cols], sep = "-")) %in% 
       do.call(paste, c(df1[cols], sep = "-")), ]

#  a1 a2 a3 a4
#1  1  2  3  9
#3  1  6  3  7
```

Comment: how about if there is a group in both, and I want to do that in each group?

Comment: also I got this error:Error: When i is a data.table (or character vector), the columns to join by must be specified either using 'on=' argument (see ?data.table) or by keying x (i.e. sorted, and, marked as sorted, see ?setkey). Keyed joins might have further speed benefits on very large data due to x being sorted in RAM.

Comment: @hghg you have got `data.table` it seems. You maybe need to convert it to data.frame first before applying the above code.

Comment: I get error when I use your codes. could you please work with data that I uploaded now?

Comment: @hghg Which are the columns you want to match now? What is your expected output for the updated data?

Comment: never mind, I made it work. now if I want to remove these row from df2 rather than selecting them what I should do? should I use ! infant ?

Comment: @hghg Add `!` sign `df2[!do.call(paste, c(df2[cols], sep = "-")) %in% 
       do.call(paste, c(df1[cols], sep = "-")), ]`

Comment: could you plz check this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58064132/how-to-add-some-value-of-columns-with-respect-of-3-groups

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr`, we can deselect column `a4` from `df1`, do an `inner_join`, and then use `distinct_all()` to remove duplicate rows.

```
library(dplyr)


df2 %>% 
  inner_join(select(df1, -a4)) %>% 
  distinct_all()

  a1 a2. a3 a4
1  1   2  3  9
2  1   6  3  7
```

Or with `base R`:

```
unique(merge(df1[,-4], df2))
```

Or:

```
unique(merge(subset(df1, select = -a4), df2))
```

Comment: the problem is u use -a4 and I have too many columns, but need to check equality for 3 columns

Comment: Then try `unique(merge(subset(df1, select = c(a1, a2, a3), df2))`?

Comment: Or `df2 %>% 
  inner_join(select(df1, a1, a2, a3)) %>% 
  distinct_all()`

Comment: if I have same group in both data set, can I do that in each group?

Comment: also gives me error: Error in subset.data.frame(NonJointTrip, select = c("ARR_HR", "ARR_MIN",  : 
  'subset' must be logical

Comment: Then please update your question with data that does represent your data